# How to insert a backslash into a string?

Tags: php

This variable should work as a download link:

```
$Path = "Downloads\Quality\$c\$c $row[name].docx";
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: And wrapping your variables in `{}` - `$Path = "Downloads\Quality\{$c}\{$c} {$row[name]}.docx";`. Also escaping the escaper - `$Path = "Downloads\\Quality\\$c\\$c $row[name].docx";`

Comment: use `$Path = urlencode("Downloads\Quality\$c\$c $row[name].docx");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backslash is the escape character. When it's before `$`, it disables the variable expansion. To turn off backslash's special behavior, put another backslash before it to escape it.

```
$Path = "Downloads\\Quality\\$c\\$c $row[name].docx";
```

However, in URLs, directories in the path should be separated with `/`, not `\`. So it should be:

```
$Path = "Downloads/Quality/$c/$c $row[name].docx";
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful norm is to leave no space in a string. When coding for an URL, it might be better to encode space (e.g. '%20') although the suggested double quotes or php 'urlencode' function may have taken care of it reasonably well.